# Convert time from Military to standard AM/PM Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-format

What if you just have a time field that is stored as a `char` and displays in military time, example (1015), and you just want to format it to standard time using sql code.  Is there a way to do that?

**Update:**

To clarify, I am defining "standard time" as meaning 6:30 PM or 4:30AM.

Comment: Can you describe what you consider as the standard format for time?

Comment: Parse it to a real date, and then format it any way you want.  https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/.  However, it's generally better to store your dates as actual dates in SQL Server, and format them in your application.

Comment: Standard time like 6:30 PM, or 4:30AM. Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to insert a colon into your military time:

```
DECLARE @Time CHAR(4) = '1015';
SELECT  STUFF(@Time, 3, 0, ':');
```

Which gives `10:15`

Then you can convert it to the Time data type:

```
DECLARE @Time CHAR(4) = '1015';
SELECT  CONVERT(TIME, STUFF(@Time, 3, 0, ':'));
```

Which gives `10:15:00.0000000`

Finally you can convert back to varchar, with the style 100 to get it in a 12 hour format:

```
DECLARE @Time CHAR(4) = '1015';
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), CONVERT(TIME, STUFF(@Time, 3, 0, ':')), 100);
```

Which gives `10:15AM`

Or

```
DECLARE @Time CHAR(4) = '2157';
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), CONVERT(TIME, STUFF(@Time, 3, 0, ':')), 100);
```

Which gives `9:57PM`

The standard way to deal with this though would be to store the time using the `TIME` datatype, and do all formatting in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Converting Military DateTime to Standard DateTIme

```
Select Convert(VarChar, Convert(Datetime,'01/12/2024 13:01:7',101),100)
```

Result:

```
Jan 12 2024  1:01PM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize the string parsing you could just strip out the hour and minutes fairly readily. This also doesn't assume the length is 4 characters or do any related adjustments to compensate for the lack of a leading zero:

```
timefromparts(cast(col as int) / 100, cast(col as int) % 100, 0, 0, 0)
```